# Definite integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-x^2 y^2) \; dx dy$?

Tags: definite-integrals, maple, wolfram-alpha

The deceptively simple-looking double integral
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty   \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \exp(-x^2 y^2) \; dx dy
$$ is clearly finite, but both maple and Wolphram alpha gives the value $\infty$!
Any ideas how to calculate this symbolically?

Comment: Why is it “clearly” finite?

Answer (score 6):

Note for $y>0$ we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2y^2}\;dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{y}
$$
so
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2y^2}\;dx\;dy \ge
\int_0^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2y^2}\;dx\;dy
=\sqrt{\pi}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{dy}{y} = +\infty.
$$

Wolfram Alpha is right for once!

Comment: I was just thinking about this question while having a preconception that the decay at $\infty$ seems good enough to regulate the integral. :) It was inside a thin strip containing the origin that the integral diverges!

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{-t}^{+t}\int_{-t}^{+t} \exp(-x^2 y^2) \, dx \, dy=4 t^2 \,\,
   _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};
   -t^4\right)$$

For large $t$
$$\large\color{blue}{I\sim \sqrt{\pi } \,\,(4 \log (t)+\gamma +2\log (2))}$$ which is very good for any $t>1$.

If $t=e$ the difference is $4.65\times 10^{-27}$.

If you want more terms, just add
$$\frac{e^{-t^4}}{t^6} \left(1-\frac{2}{t^4}+\frac{23}{4
   t^8}-\frac{22}{t^{12}}+\frac{1689}{16
   t^{16}}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^{20}}\right)\right) $$

**Edit**

For those we want to play, give Wolfram Alpha the following

`Series[4*t^2*HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1/2}, {3/2, 3/2}, -t^4],{t,Infinity,6}]`

Comment: May I ask how did you get the blue approximation?

Comment: @Zima. For sure, you may ! This is just an asymptotic analysis; nothing more. For the fun, I added the next portion which is absolutely of no use or interest. Cheers :-)

Comment: But I'm curious: how did you come up with those specific numbers? Like $\sqrt\pi$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: @Zima. I added the WA syntax in an edit. Have fun changing the $6$ to whatever. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks very much